# Prove $(log {(n)})^k = O(n)$ by definition, not by limit

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How can I prove $(log {(n)})^k = O(n)$  (for any constant $k > 0$) by definition, not by the limit?

By definition, that mean. there exists C, N such that:
$$(log {(n)})^k = Cn$$ with $n > N.$
I tried by induction but fail.

My professor want to prove it without using limit method.

Comment: Can you show that $log(n) = O(n)$? Then it'll be easy to pick the necessary constants.

Comment: Maybe similar to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511762/log-nk-on-for-k-greater-or-equal-to-1

Comment: It should be $(\log n)^k\leq Cn$

Comment: @NoChance not similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a series of steps/hints that'll take you there:

1. Write $n = e^x$.  Then you want to find a constant $C$ and $N$ so that for all $x \geq \log(N)$ we have $$x^k \leq C e^x\,.$$
2. Show that for all $x > 0$, $\frac{x^k}{k!} < e^x$.

---

Edit: Misread the question, edited accordingly.

Comment: How can I prove the 2. ?

Comment: any one could clarify point 2 for me ? Thanks.

Comment: As a hint,what is the definition of $e^x$?  (think taylor expansion)

Comment: Thank you. This is Taylor expansion: $\epsilon^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $. We clearly see that $ \frac{x^k}{k!} < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} $